# Display error message when ajax result return null value

Tags: php, sql, ajax, error-messages-for

I would like to ask how to display error message when null value and 0 value in the ajax result from SQL

```
{"value":
    {"columns": [["More than 85%",null],["Less than 85%",0]],
    "type":"pie"}
}
```

else no pop out message shown.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "charts/prod.php?year=" + $("#selectyear").val() + "&month=" + $("#selectmonth").val(),
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (result) { 
        var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#piepie',
            data: result.value,
            color: { 
                pattern: ['#f35213', '#f1af4c'] 
            },
            pie: { title: "Productivity", }
        });     
    },
    error: function() {
        if ((result == null) && (result == 0)){ 
            alert ('Data are not ready yet!!');  
        } 
        else {
            ('error');
        }
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `result` doesn't exist in the `error:` function. You need to do that test in the `success:` function.

The `null` and `0` values are deep in the structure, you need to access them properly.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "charts/prod.php?year=" + $("#selectyear").val() + "&month=" + $("#selectmonth").val(),
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.value.columns[0][1] == null && result.value.columns[1][1] == 0) {
            alert ('Data are not ready yet!!');
        } else {
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#piepie',
                data: result.value,
                color: { 
                    pattern: ['#f35213', '#f1af4c'] 
                },
                pie: { title: "Productivity", }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }   
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the PHP script is returning `json_encode(null)` or `json_encode(0)` when there's no data available?

Comment: Maybe you should be testing `if (result.value == null)` instead of `if (result == null)`?

Comment: {"value":{"columns":[["More than 85%",null],["Less than 85%",0]],"type":"pie"}}
the result is null and 0

Comment: That's `result.value.columns[0][1] == null` and `result.value.columns[1][1] == 0`.

Comment: {"percentage":["-100","0","-50","-50","0"],"new":"0","pending":"0","completed":"1","ongoing":"1","delay":"1"}

Comment: What is that supposed to be?

Comment: if i wan to display msg when {"percentage":["-100","0","-50","-50","0"],"new":"0","pendin‌​g":"0","completed":"‌​0","ongoing":"0","de‌​lay":"0"}  when new,pending, completed,ongoing and delay are 0 then how to write the condition

Comment: Why is this so hard for you? It's just objects and arrays. To access an object property you use `.propertyname`, to access an array element you use `[index]`. This is beginner stuff, you need to learn the language.

Comment: I guess you didn't really learn much from my answer. It seems like you just know how to copy, you don't understand the general principles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "charts/prod.php?year=" + $("#selectyear").val() + "&month=" + $("#selectmonth").val(),
   dataType: "json", 
   success: function (result) { 
      if ((result == null) && (result == 0)){ 
        alert ('Data are not ready yet!!');  
      }else {
          var chart = c3.generate({
               bindto: '#piepie',
               data: result.value,
               color: { 
               pattern: ['#f35213', '#f1af4c'] },
               pie: { title: "Productivity", }
          });
       }        
   },
   error: function() {
      alert('error'); 
   }   
 });
```

Comment: can you post your response here ?? just want to see what response send by server and according to that i can suggest.